# Error on the wei value in Remix

Tags: transactions, remix, ico

I would like to deploy a smart contract ICO on the testnet (Ropsten) and for that I use Remix.

The problem is : if i deploy my SC with value = 0 wei it's okay, but after when I try to do a transaction using transferFrom and isn't possible (I have the Error: gas required exceeds allowance or always failing transaction).

And I try to put a value = x wei (x is a number, ex:10000) it doesn't work ...
Someone know how to put a value and success to deploy the SC ?

Thanks you in advance for your help !

[image]

Here is the code of my SC :

```
pragma solidity 0.4.21;

contract ERC20Basic {
  uint256 public totalSupply;
  function balanceOf(address who) public view returns (uint256);
  function transfer(address to, uint256 value) public returns (bool);
  event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);
}

contract ERC20 is ERC20Basic {
  function allowance(address owner, address spender) public view returns (uint256);
  function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint256 value) public returns (bool);
  function approve(address spender, uint256 value) public returns (bool);
  event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint256 value);
}

library SafeMath {
      function mul(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
    if (a == 0) {
      return 0;
    }
    uint256 c = a * b;
    assert(c / a == b);
    return c;
  }

  function div(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
// assert(b > 0); // Solidity automatically throws when dividing by 0
    uint256 c = a / b;
// assert(a == b * c + a % b); 
    return c;
  }

  function sub(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
assert(b <= a);
return a - b;
  }

  function add(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
uint256 c = a + b;
assert(c >= a);
return c;
  }
}


contract BasicToken is ERC20Basic {
  using SafeMath for uint256;

  mapping(address => uint256) balances;

  function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool) {
require(_to != address(0));
require(_value <= balances[msg.sender]);

// SafeMath.sub will throw if there is not enough balance.
balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender].sub(_value);
balances[_to] = balances[_to].add(_value);
emit Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
return true;
  }

  function balanceOf(address _owner) public view returns (uint256 balance) {
return balances[_owner];
  }

}

contract StandardToken is ERC20, BasicToken {

  mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) internal allowed;

  function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool) {
require(_to != address(0));
require(_value <= balances[_from]);
require(_value <= allowed[_from][msg.sender]);

balances[_from] = balances[_from].sub(_value);
balances[_to] = balances[_to].add(_value);
allowed[_from][msg.sender] = allowed[_from][msg.sender].sub(_value);
emit Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
return true;
  }

  function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) public returns (bool) {
allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;
emit Approval(msg.sender, _spender, _value);
return true;
  }

  function allowance(address _owner, address _spender) public view returns (uint256) {
return allowed[_owner][_spender];
  }

  function increaseApproval(address _spender, uint _addedValue) public returns (bool) {
allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = allowed[msg.sender][_spender].add(_addedValue);
emit Approval(msg.sender, _spender, allowed[msg.sender][_spender]);
return true;
  }

        function decreaseApproval(address _spender, uint _subtractedValue) public returns (bool) {
uint oldValue = allowed[msg.sender][_spender];
if (_subtractedValue > oldValue) {
  allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = 0;
} else {
  allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = oldValue.sub(_subtractedValue);
}
emit Approval(msg.sender, _spender, allowed[msg.sender][_spender]);
return true;
  }

    }

contract Ownable {
   address public owner;


   event OwnershipTransferred(address indexed previousOwner, address indexed newOwner);


  function Ownable() public {
owner = msg.sender;
  }

   modifier onlyOwner() {
require(msg.sender == owner);
_;
  }


  function transferOwnership(address newOwner) public onlyOwner {
require(newOwner != address(0));
emit OwnershipTransferred(owner, newOwner);
owner = newOwner;
  }

}

contract Pausable is Ownable {
   event Pause();
   event Unpause();

  bool public paused = false;

  modifier whenNotPaused() {
require(!paused);
_;
  }

  modifier whenPaused() {
require(paused);
_;
  }

  function pause() onlyOwner whenNotPaused public {
paused = true;
emit Pause();
  }

   function unpause() onlyOwner whenPaused public {
paused = false;
emit Unpause();
  }
 }

contract PausableToken is StandardToken, Pausable {

  function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public whenNotPaused returns (bool) {
return super.transfer(_to, _value);
  }

   function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) public whenNotPaused returns (bool) {
return super.transferFrom(_from, _to, _value);
   }

  function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) public whenNotPaused returns (bool) {
return super.approve(_spender, _value);
  }

  function increaseApproval(address _spender, uint _addedValue) public whenNotPaused returns (bool success) {
return super.increaseApproval(_spender, _addedValue);
  }

   function decreaseApproval(address _spender, uint _subtractedValue) public whenNotPaused returns (bool success) {
return super.decreaseApproval(_spender, _subtractedValue);
 }
}

contract Test is StandardToken, PausableToken {
   string public constant name = 'Test';                                      // Set the token name for display
   string public constant symbol = 'TEST';                                       // Set the token symbol for display
   uint8 public constant decimals = 18;                                          // Set the number of decimals for display
   uint256 public constant INITIAL_SUPPLY = 50000000000 * 10**uint256(decimals);  // 50 billions 

  function Test() public{
totalSupply = INITIAL_SUPPLY;                               // Set the total supply
balances[msg.sender] = INITIAL_SUPPLY;                      // Creator address is assigned all
emit Transfer(0x0, msg.sender, INITIAL_SUPPLY);
  }

   function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public whenNotPaused returns (bool) {
require(_to != address(0));
return super.transfer(_to, _value);
   }

   function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) public whenNotPaused returns (bool) {
require(_to != address(0));
return super.transferFrom(_from, _to, _value);
   }

  function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) public whenNotPaused returns (bool) {
return super.approve(_spender, _value);
  }

    event Burn(address indexed _burner, uint _value);

    function burn(uint _value) public returns (bool)
{
    balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender].sub(_value);
    totalSupply = totalSupply.sub(_value);
    emit Burn(msg.sender, _value);
    emit Transfer(msg.sender, address(0x0), _value);
    return true;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are talking about two different actions here.

1. When deploying your token initially, you probably don't want to send any value along with it.  If you do (for some reason), then the contract you deploy `Test` must have a `payable` constructor.
2. When calling `transferFrom()`, you are probably failing on one of the following require statements:

   ```
   require(_value <= balances[_from]);
   require(_value <= allowed[_from][msg.sender]);
   ```

Make sure the address you are transferring from actually has tokens assigned to it, and make sure the address you are transferring to has been allowed to make this transaction.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. 1. I only say that because I have read "you must do a value if you want to transfer some token along with your transaction". 2. Yes, it's me who deploy the SC and therefore  I have 50 billion token, and when I try to use the function tranferFrom I put : 0x95Ea183985ea4F5f2a18bf07dB37eB401e768c73,0x48a484a13bb7b08c8f0022c538e871cb4417e5c9,10 or "0x95Ea183985ea4F5f2a18bf07dB37eB401e768c73","0x48a484a13bb7b08c8f0022c538e871cb4417e5c9",10 but I always have the Error: gas required exceeds allowance or always failing transaction

Comment: When deploying a token contract as you have described in your code, it is not necessary to provide additional value in wei along with the transaction.  

As for your issue with calling `transferFrom()`, the address who you wish to transfer FROM must add the address who you wish to transfer TO to the `allowed` mapping.

I am unsure what you are attempting to do, but maybe a simple `transfer()` is what you are looking for if you are trying to simply send tokens from A -> B.

Comment: Yes, you are right when I use the function transfer it's okay and finally that's what I wanted. Thanks you very much !!! When do we use the function TransferFrom ??

Comment: `transferFrom` is generally used to when address A wants to send tokens from address B to somewhere else.  As you might expect, address B must first allow address A access to do this with a certain amount.